# How to get CPU, RAM and DISK using single command

Tags: linux

There are set of VM in production and staging environment. I need to get CPU, Memory and Disk capacity of all VMs. Is there any single command to get those at once?

Comment: You should be able to do this with a API call to the VM infra vendor.

Comment: @RamanSailopal, getting those info from infra vendor is super long process in my environment

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to get above details at once.

```
free -m | grep Mem | awk -F' ' '{printf "Mem : %s \nCPU: ", $2}' ; cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor  | wc -l ;df -h |grep G | awk -F' ' '{print($2)}' | awk -F'G' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ sum += $i;} printf "DISK : %s \n", sum;}'| tail -1
```

Comment: Piping grep to awk is an unnecessary, bad practice.

Comment: @RamanSailopal, any other way to get those info?

Comment: `free -m |awk -F' ' '/Mem/ {printf "Mem : %s \nCPU : ", $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

Using awk as a "complete" solution without the need for numerous pipes to grep etc:

One liner:

```
awk '/^Mem:/ { mem=$2 } /^processor/ { pcnt++ } /^Filesystem/ { filesys=1;next } filesys==1 { filetot=filetot+$2;print filetot } END { printf "Memory: %s\nProcessor Total: %s\nDisk size total: %.2f\n",mem,pcnt,filetot }' <(free -m) /proc/cpuinfo <(df -h)
```

Explanation:

```
awk '/^Mem:/ { 
               mem=$2 # Search for a line beginning with "Mem:" in the output and set a mem variable
             } 
     /^processor/ { 
               pcnt++ # For each line that starts "processor" increment a pcnt variable
             } 
     /^Filesystem/ { 
               filesys=1; # Set a tracking filesys variable when a line is encountered beginning with "Filesystem"
               next # Skip to the next line
              } 
     filesys==1 { 
               filetot=filetot+$2; # When we are in the file system section, total the disk sizes (the second space delimited field)
              } 
     END { 
               printf "Memory: %s\nProcessor Total: %s\nDisk size total: %.2f\n",mem,pcnt,filetot # Once we have processed all lines of the output, print the data we want.
         }' <(free -m) /proc/cpuinfo <(df -h) # Redirect command back into awk to process the output
```